# Hibernate one to one with multiple columns

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

How can i bind two columns, using @OneToOne annotation?

Lets say I've 2 tables A and B.

Table A:

- id1 (primary key)
- id2 (pk)
- other columns

Table B:

- id1 (pk)
- id2 (pk)
- other columns

In class A i want to write something like this:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = B.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "id1 and id2", referencedColumnName = "id1 and id2")
private B b;
```

Is it possible to do this using annotations?

Thanks.

Comment: This will help. http://www.thejavageek.com/tag/compound-primary-keys/

Comment: @Ordous, funny, I used Google and got this question...

Answer (score 1):

What you need is composite keys.Use either `@IdClass` or `@EmbeddedId`

Example of `@EmbeddedId` something like this.

your composite key class:

```
@Embeddable
public class CompositePK implements Serializable {
    protected Integer id1;
    protected Integer id2;


    // equals, hashCode
}
```

Your Enity class :

```
@Entity
public class A{
    @EmbeddedId 
    private CompositePK compkey;

    @OneToOne(optional=true, mappedBy="A")
    private B b;

   ........
}
```